# Trying to create predict() function that accepts a list of prediction probabilities and a threshold value and computes final predictions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a function `predict()` that accepts as input a list of prediction probabilities and a threshold value, and computes the final predictions to be output by the model. If a prediction probability value is less than or equal to the threshold value, then the prediction is the negative case (i.e. 0). If a prediction probability value is greater than the threshold value, then the prediction is the positive case (i.e. 1).

When I pass the prediction probabilities (predict_prob) and threshold value (thresh) to the function, I get

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to change my predict_prob list to tuples which I thought was subscriptable, but I still get the same error.  My code is below.  Can someone assist?

```
# Create predict() function that accepts a list of prediction probabilities and a threshold value
def predict(predict_prob,thresh):
    pred = []  
    for i in range(len(predict_prob)):
        if list[i] >= thresh: 
            pred.append(1) 
        else:
            pred.append(0)
    return pred

predict_prob = [0.886,0.375,0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,0.847,0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,0.917,0.64,0.388,0.116,0.72]

thresh = 0.5

preds = predict(predict_prob, thresh)
```

Comment: Update:  I changed list[i] in the above if/else statement to just i and it runs, but doesn't produce the correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a reserved word for python and that's where the error comes from. You probably wanted to refer to `predict_prob` instead as in the corrected example below

```
# Create predict() function that accepts a list of prediction probabilities and a threshold value
def predict(predict_prob,thresh):
    pred = []  
    for i in range(len(predict_prob)):
        if predict_prob[i] >= thresh: 
            pred.append(1) 
        else:
            pred.append(0)
    return pred

predict_prob = [0.886,0.375,0.174,0.817,0.574,0.319,0.812,0.314,0.098,0.741,0.847,0.202,0.31,0.073,0.179,0.917,0.64,0.388,0.116,0.72]

thresh = 0.5

preds = predict(predict_prob, thresh)
```

One faster way to do that is using `numpy` arrays since it will be the following

```
import numpy as np
def predict(predict_prob, thresh):
   bool_res = np.array(predict_prob)>thresh
   return 1*bool_res
```

Comment: Thank you DaSim that worked! Seems like a silly mistake but when you're learning I guess they're all silly mistakes.

Comment: Especially at the beginning! Since I helped you, please accept my answer so then I can get reputation points!

Comment: Hi I'm trying to find where I accept your answer (new to stackoverflow too).  An online search says there should be a checkmark next to your answer that I can click, but I don't see it.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work can help you

Comment: Found it!  Let me know if it didn't register and thank you again.

Comment: It did! Thanks and welcome to stackoverflow